# SQL Script between multiple table name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime

```
 ---------table_01_01_2016----------
|    Name     |       Datetime      |
| Tom         | 01/01/2016 17:50:00 |
| Tomas       | 01/01/2016 17:55:00 |
| Sara        | 01/01/2016 17:58:00 |
-----------------------------------

 ---------table_02_01_2016----------
|    Name     |       Datetime      |
| Tom         | 02/01/2016 16:50:00 |
| Tomas       | 02/01/2016 16:55:00 |
| Sara        | 02/01/2016 16:58:00 |
-----------------------------------

 ---------table_03_01_2016----------
|    Name     |       Datetime      |
| Tom         | 03/01/2016 17:51:00 |
| Tomas       | 03/01/2016 17:52:00 |
| Sara        | 03/01/2016 17:53:00 |
-----------------------------------
.
.
.
.
 ---------table_30_06_2016----------
|    Name     |       Datetime      |
| Tom         | 30/06/2016 17:50:00 |
| Tomas       | 30/06/2016 17:55:00 |
| Sara        | 30/06/2016 17:58:00 |
-----------------------------------
```

Tables are created every day.
I want to summary multiple Tables.

```
 --Summary_01_01_2016 to Summary_30_06_2016--
|           Name      |       Datetime      |
| Tom                 | 01/01/2016 17:50:00 |
| Tomas               | 01/01/2016 17:55:00 |
| Sara                | 01/01/2016 17:58:00 |
| Tom                 | 02/01/2016 16:50:00 |
| Tomas               | 02/01/2016 16:55:00 |
| Sara                | 02/01/2016 16:58:00 | 
| Tom                 | 03/01/2016 17:51:00 |
| Tomas               | 03/01/2016 17:52:00 |
| Sara                | 03/01/2016 17:53:00 |   
.
.
.
.
.
| Tom                 | 30/06/2016 17:50:00 |
| Tomas               | 30/06/2016 17:55:00 |
| Sara                | 30/06/2016 17:58:00 |
---------------------------------------------
```

I don't script join table in long.
Thanks for help me ^^

Comment: Fix your process to insert rows into a single table rather than creating different tables.  A single table is the right way to store this type of data.

Comment: If you can't do the above, UNION ALL is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)

;WITH cte AS (
SELECT CAST('2016-01-01' as datetime) as d
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(day,1,d)
FROM cte
WHERE d < '2016-06-30'
) -- table contains dates from needed interval

SELECT @sql = (
SELECT 'SELECT * FROM table_' + REPLACE(CONVERT(nvarchar(10),d,104),'.','_') + ' UNION ALL ' + CHAR(10)
FROM cte
FOR XML PATH('')
) --creating a script
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)

PRINT @sql

--EXEC sp_executesql @sql --this will execute script
```

Output:

```
SELECT * FROM table_01_01_2016 UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM table_02_01_2016 UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM table_03_01_2016 UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM table_04_01_2016 UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM table_05_01_2016 UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM table_06_01_2016 UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM table_07_01_2016 UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM table_08_01_2016 UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM table_09_01_2016 UNION ALL 
..
```

etc

Comment: I want to change date time Output:
SELECT * FROM table_2016_01_01 UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM table_2016_01_02 UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM table_2016_01_03 UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM table_2016_01_04 UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM table_2016_01_05 UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM table_2016_01_06 

What should I do?

Comment: Change 104 on 102 in CONVERT part!

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say as your "question" lacks any meaningful detail..

However, it's nearly Friday and I am on holiday soon so.......

Look at UNION and UNION ALL

Perhaps that can help you.

Comment: Is it possible for us to take SQL Script Between table which table name  such as     

SELECT * 
FROM [table_01_01_2016] AS a 
WHERE EXISTS 
      ( SELECT 1
        FROM table_30_06_2016 AS b 
        WHERE a.Datetime BETWEEN a.Datetime.01/01/2016 AND
        b.Datetime.03/01/2016
      ) ;

Answer (score 0):

You can use union all.

```
Select * From table_01_01_2016
Union All
Select * From table_02_01_2016
Union All
Select...
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean exactly.  If you want a dynamic way to do what you are after check out this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32210193/run-the-same-query-against-multiple-tables-without-dynamic-sql

Comment: Is it possible for us to take SQL Script Between table which table name  such as     

SELECT * 
FROM [table_01_01_2016] AS a 
WHERE EXISTS 
      ( SELECT 1
        FROM table_30_06_2016 AS b 
        WHERE a.Datetime BETWEEN a.Datetime.01/01/2016 AND
        b.Datetime.03/01/2016
      ) ;