# Track table counts from a schema

Tags: sql, postgresql

I use postgres and I need some help from you all PG experts...
I am looking to track counts from a large set of source tables whose counts keep changing everyday. I want to use the tablename, row count and tablesize in a tracker table, and a column called created_dttm field to show when this row count is recorded from source table. This is for trending how the table counts are changing with time and look for peaks.

```
insert into tracker_table( tablename, rowcount, tablesize, timestamp)
from 
(
(select schema.tablename ... - not sure how to drive this to pick up a list of tables??
, select count(*) from schema.tablename
, SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size('"schema"."tablename"'))
, select created_dttm from schema.tablename
)
);
```

Additionally, I want to get a particular column from source table for a fourth column. This would be a created_dttm timestamp field in the source table, and I want to run a simple sql to get this date to the tracker table. Any suggestions how to attack this problem?

Comment: Is the list of tables you need to examine static, or does your process need to account for new tables coming in/being deleted?

Comment: Thanks for your response, the list of tables is static

Comment: You could simply write the same query for each table.  A better way still, though, you would need to use dynamic SQL.  What I would do, is make a function that gets passed the table name and dynamically executes the query you need.  Then you'd just statically call said function on each table, or alternatively, query nformation_schema.tables (which you would have to do if your list of tables wasn't static.  Also, this answer has some discussion of issues that are probably relevant you:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32210193/run-the-same-query-against-multiple-tables-without-dynamic-sql

Comment: Very interesting! I need to dig up the corresponding postgres sql notation. I see what you mean. I could do multiple select for the specific table and get the counts. I am looking for a way to get a loop of a list of tables which will then run the queries to populate to tracker. I dont want to do insert values 'table1', select... then insert 'table2', select.. individually populating the tablename field

Comment: This kind of has what you mention:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24618672/function-to-loop-through-and-select-data-from-multiple-tables  Keep in mind, you can only do dynamic sql in a PG/PGSQL function in postgres.

Comment: sovemp, thanks, but this does not work for my need right now. Good to learn about it :)

Answer (score 1):

before reading the code please consider this:

1. instead of selecting several subqueries, this if you can join them into one qry, eg `select (select 1 from t), (select 2 from t)` can be refactored to `select 1,2 from t`
2. `pg_total_relation_size` is sum of data pages, so it is size of table, but not size of data in it.
3. you need aggregation on your `created_dttm` column (I used oid instead), otherwise your subquery returns more then one row, so you won't be able to insert the result.
4. instead of `select count(*)` maybe use `pg_stat_all_tables` stats?.. counting can be very expensive and acuracy of the count(*) is neglected by the fact that next minute same select count(*) will be different and you probably wont run this count every two seconds...

code:

```
t=# create table so30 (n text, c int, s text, o int);
CREATE TABLE

t=# do
$$
declare
  _r record;
  _s text;
begin
  for _r in (values('pg_database'),('pg_roles')) loop
    _s := format('select %1$L,(select count(*) from %1$I), (SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size(%1$L))), (select max(oid) from %1$I)',_r.column1);
    execute format('insert into so30 %s',_s);
  end loop;
end;
$$
;
DO
t=# select * from so30;
      n      | c |    s    |   o
-------------+---+---------+-------
 pg_database | 4 | 72 kB   | 16384
 pg_roles    | 2 | 0 bytes |  4200
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks, you have raised very interesting points. I think the looping structure comes close to what I will need, although your answer does not fully answer my question. I need to find a count for the tables by a timestamp. A table will have N timestamps, I want a count for all those timestamp, along with the larger nested loop for all the tables M similarly.