# Saving table stats into a table, including the table name

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-cursor

I'm running into a wall compiling row updates and new rows in a few tables to save off in another table for trending. I know a cursor could achieve this pretty easily and I get a result set, but I'm struggling to figure out how to get these into a table with the cursor (or if I should approach it completely differently.

###### Background

I want to calculate and save off daily the number of new and edited rows daily from several tables of interest in a `production` database. These tables' rows are timestamped with the last edit.

My `stats` database that contains a `tablestats` table that will house the information for each table across 6 columns. My goal in mind is to run an Agent job daily to count the prior day's timestamps, the delta between today's rowcount and the prior day's rowcount, and then merge those into `tablestats`.

Something like this:

| tablename | updyear | updmonth | updday | rowupdates | newrows |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| table_1 | 2023 | 2 | 5 | 2509 | 34 |
| table_1 | 2023 | 2 | 6 | 3443 | 90 |
| table_2 | 2023 | 2 | 5 | 834 | 255 |
| table_2 | 2023 | 2 | 6 | 544 | 433 |

With that, I can trend/pivot the data as needed.

###### What I tried

I figured a cursor would in part be the best approach since I was having trouble condensing the query's results with the name of the table I'm pulling from. I adapted this [question & answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32210193/run-the-same-query-against-multiple-tables-without-dynamic-sql) to get part of the way there, but I'm struggling with how to take the next step. I abbreviated the below code for legibility:

```
DECLARE @last_upd nvarchar(MAX) = '';
DECLARE @checkdate date = DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE());

SELECT @last_upd = @last_upd + 'SELECT '''
+QUOTENAME(name)
+''',YEAR(last_upd) as updyear /* month, etc. */,COUNT(last_upd) as rowupdates FROM ' 
+ QUOTENAME(name) 
+ ' WHERE last_upd > @checkdate /* GROUP BY year/month/day*/; '
FROM sys.tables
WHERE (name IN ('table_1','table_2','table_3'))

IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0 
EXEC sp_executesql @last_upd
, N'@checkdate date'
, @checkdate'
```

Which returns the following:

| Query 1 | updyear | updmonth | updday | rowupdates |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| table_1 | 2023 | 2 | 5 |  |
| table_1 | 2023 | 2 | 6 |  |

| Query 2 | updyear | updmonth | updday | rowupdates |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| table_2 | 2023 | 2 | 5 |  |
| table_2 | 2023 | 2 | 6 |  |

Query 3, etc.

Since it returns as 3 separate queries, I'm unsure how to get that into a merge statement, since I can't `SELECT * INTO #temptable` with these.

The reason I'm interested in merge even though it's a daily run is to accomodate any potential conflicts with existing data. I haven't gotten to the point of doing a rowcount but assume at worst, I could do a second cursor with the rowcount prior to rolling it up into a stored procedure.

Comment: So what is your question? I can't work out what you are stuck on...

Comment: There's no clear question here. Please edit and add clarity with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and clearly explain the problem; [tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)

Comment: Why do you think you need a cursor here? It looks like just selecting some of the columns. The real problem though is this question makes no sense. But why oh why are you storing data like this in the first place?

Comment: @SeanLange It must be terrible phrasing on my part, and please forgive my ignorance but what issues do you see with the data storage?  I thought periodically snapshotting the metrics wouldbe the best way to make future trending easier. I unfortunately don't have any control over the data source.

Comment: Once you start storing the table name you need to query in a table you are going down a very slippery slope. It forces you to use dynamic sql which can become quite challenging and potentially expose yourself to sql injection if not handled correctly.

Answer (score 0):

What you really want is a `UNION ALL` to combine the results from the various queries into a single result set. If you change your dynamic `SELECT` to a `UNION ALL SELECT`, you are most of the way there. What's left is to strip the leading occurence using something like `SET @last_upd = STUFF(@last_upd, 1, 10, '')`, which replaces the first 10 characters with nothing.

If you include a newline immediately after the opening quote of your dynamic statement, the generated SQL will look a lot nicer when you print it out during debugging.

It is also common to now use `STRING_AGG()` to to combine generated code snippets when generating dynamic SQL, but your approach works so I'll leave it.

For the table name column in the result, you can use `QUOTENAME(..., '''')` to safely stringify the name inside single quotes instead of `[]`.

The updated code would be something like:

```
DECLARE @last_upd nvarchar(MAX) = '';
DECLARE @checkdate date = DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE());

SELECT @last_upd = @last_upd + '
UNION ALL
SELECT '
    + QUOTENAME(name, '''')
    + ',YEAR(last_upd) as updyear /* month, etc. */,COUNT(last_upd) as rowupdates FROM ' 
    + QUOTENAME(name) 
    + ' WHERE last_upd > @checkdate GROUP BY YEAR(last_upd) /* year/month/day*/ '
FROM sys.tables
WHERE (name IN ('table_1','table_2','table_3'))

SET @last_upd = STUFF(@last_upd, 1, 10, '')
  
SELECT @last_upd
  
IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0 
EXEC sp_executesql @last_upd
, N'@checkdate date'
, @checkdate
```

Generated SQL:

```
SELECT 'table_1',YEAR(last_upd) as updyear /* month, etc. */,COUNT(last_upd) as rowupdates FROM [table_1] WHERE last_upd > @checkdate GROUP BY YEAR(last_upd) /* year/month/day*/ 
UNION ALL
SELECT 'table_2',YEAR(last_upd) as updyear /* month, etc. */,COUNT(last_upd) as rowupdates FROM [table_2] WHERE last_upd > @checkdate GROUP BY YEAR(last_upd) /* year/month/day*/ 
UNION ALL
SELECT 'table_3',YEAR(last_upd) as updyear /* month, etc. */,COUNT(last_upd) as rowupdates FROM [table_3] WHERE last_upd > @checkdate GROUP BY YEAR(last_upd) /* year/month/day*/
```

Results:

| (No column name) | updyear | rowupdates |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [table_1] | 2023 | 2 |
| [table_2] | 2023 | 1 |
| [table_3] | 2023 | 3 |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qAs5jhAQ)

I'll leave it to you to finish up the details to get your complete desired result.